# Safari load PHP script two times

Tags: php, safari

I have a problem with this code in Safari (in Firefox and Chrome it works)

When I load the page, in the file created rows are duplicated. 
If you reload the page without closing the browser tab the script works well.

[I attach a video to better understand](http://youtu.be/O9zHZFBLjWI)

```
$fileName = 'test.txt';
$d = date("d/m/Y - H:i:s");
echo $d . "<br>\n";
echo '------------------------------------------' . "<br>\n";

file_put_contents($fileName, $d . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

$lines = file($fileName);
foreach($lines as $lineNum => $line) {
    echo "Line #" . ++$lineNum . " : " . $line . "<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure the file was clean before you ran in Safari?

Comment: Yes, the file is created on the first run of the script and then the data are added to the existing ones in the queue. 

However, even if the file exists, two lines are added to the first run of the script.

Comment: Safari seems to execute the script while you are typing in the URL.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean. If you're referring to the video, am I reloading the page by clicking on the address bar and pressing enter. 

It looks like a bug in Safari. In Chrome and Firefox the script works fine.

Comment: Do the following: Open up the finder window where the file is being created. Make sure it is not created yet or delete it. Now, open Safari, but make sure you can still see the finder window where the file will be created. Now, begin to type out the url for your test server, looks like localhost. Safari will autofill it for you… but but you should notice that the file gets created without you actually visiting the page. Let me know if I am correct.

Comment: You're right. I tried what you said and it is true. 
I had not noticed this weird behavior of Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple:

> Engineering has determined that this issue behaves as intended based
>   on the following:
>
> This occurs because we preload Top Hits in the background when it
>   appears likely that they'll be selected from the completion list. This
>   behavior can be disabled from Safari's Privacy preference pane via the
>   "Do not preload Top Hit in the background" checkbox.

Comment: I disabled the preload from the Safari preferences and the script works. 

Thank you so much for the tip.